# Can I override/delegate assignment operator?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I began learn Groovy, and faced the challenge.

I have this code, that stores meta-data to object:

```
class Meta {
    final MetaItem name
    final MetaItem description
    // ...
    // And more fields with type MetaItem
    // ...

    Meta() {
        name = new MetaItem("name")
        description = new MetaItem("description")
    }

    void setName(String name) {
        this.name.value = name
    }

    String getName() {
        return this.name.value
    }

    void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description.value = description
    }

    String getDescription() {
        return this.description.value
    }

    // ...
    // And more methods. Two for each field
    // ...
}

class MetaItem {
    private final def id
    def value

    MetaItem(String id) {
        this.id = id
    }
}

// Validating

def meta = new Meta()

assert meta.name == null
assert meta.description == null

meta.with {
    name = "Name"
    description = "Desc"
}

assert meta.name == "Name"
assert meta.description == "Desc"

print "Success!"
```

As you can see from the code, it increases quicly in volumes when new fields are added, because for each field you need to add two methods. Can this somehow be optimized? Redirect the assignment operation from object to his member. I've looked on Delegate, but this is not what I need.

P.S. I can't use access by `.value` because this class is used in Gradle extension and I need to configure it like this:

```
myExtension {
    meta {
        name = "Name"
        description = "Desc"
        // And many others
    }
}
```

P.P.S. Sorry for my bad english, it's not my first language

Comment: Can't you use `@Delegate`?

Comment: How it use correctly in my case? I've tried to understand, but couldn't